# Load A Separate Codefile in Python

Tags: python, import, directory

I have two codefiles in python, let's say mainfile.py and separatecode.py. I would like to run separatecode.py from within mainfile.py, referencing the specific directory where separatecode.py is stored.

So the pseudocode of what I am looking to do would be something like:

import C:\Users\Jack\Documents\MyFolder\separatecode.py

A number of questions discuss importing, but I can't find one that discusses importing a specific file you wrote in a particular directory. I would like to be able to use functions defined in separatecode.py and am looking for the equivalent of the source("separatecode.r") command in R if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('Module_name', 'Path\To\module.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

you dont need the `foo.MyClass()` it was just an example to show that the module works like any other module

no you can import a module from anywhere using the path and its name and you can acsess all its functions etc

for anything else check out:

[Python Imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html)

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: What does foo.MyClass() do here? From the link it seems like the first two lines would do the trick. Even simply importing imp followed by "imp.load_source('Module_name', 'Path\To\module.py')"

Comment: its just an example like foo is the module and you are using the MyClass()  you dont need it i was just showing that when you import you can use the module just like normal

Answer (score 0):

Add that directory to your `sys.path` by doing:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/directory/to/my/file')
```

Import the module as normal:

```
import separatecode
```

Comment: How does this affect my ability to import other built-in packages? So, for example, after running this code would import random still work?

Comment: @user2327821: that would still work as all other modules are also on `sys.path`. It's just that you can now also import code from the `separatecode` module.

Answer (score 0):

The code you used will not work. It will give a syntax error.

Look at the documentation for the [import statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), especially the grammar. A `module` is one or more [`identifiers`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier) separated by dots.

You can make `import separatecode` work by adding `C:\Users\Jack\Documents\MyFolder` to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. This will make it available to all Python scripts. Or you can add that path to [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) in `mainfile.py` *before* importing `separatecode`.